# lxml удаляет cdata

Tags: python, python-3.5, lxml, bs4

получаю xml документ. После того как скармливаю его сюда:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
```

пропадают все cdata. как быть?

Comment: В html не существует cdata. Если вы парсите xml, то используйте `'lxml-xml'`

Comment: Вообще, парсить xml можно было бы и напрямую с lxml без всяких BeautifulSoup

Comment: 'lxml-xml' помогло, спасибо

Comment: @andreymal с библиотеками проще

Comment: lxml это тоже библиотека как бы :)

Comment: @andreymal, понял, не так прочитал. Показалось: "напрямую БЕЗ lxml без всяких BeautifulSoup"